# How do I center a square in tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to Python, attempting to turn my board game into a simply animated dungeon crawler. I cannot figure out, however, how to center a square in the tkinter window. I have defined the center of the canvas using cMiddle. How do I move the center of the square to that point?

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, width=1000, height=700, bg='midnight blue')
c.pack()

playerID = c.create_rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150, fill='grey')
cMiddle = [int(c['width']) / 2, int(c['height']) / 2]

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Assuming the "square" is `playerID`, have you considered looking at the parameters of `create_rectangle` and replacing some of those with the data in `cMiddle`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the list containing the coordinates for the center of the canvas, you can define the width and height of the "player" rectangle (which I've assumed to be 50 given what you've already written here) and use those values together to `create_rectangle` at the center like so:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, width=1000, height=700, bg='midnight blue')
c.pack()
c_middle = [int(c['width']) / 2, int(c['height']) / 2]

# set the player size you want 
# (they don't have to be the same if you don't want the player to be square)
player_width = 50
player_height = 50

# c_middle[0] gets the canvas width from the c_middle list
# c_middle[1] gets the canvas height from the c_middle list

# player_width, player_height are divided by 2 because otherwise
# the player will be twice as wide/tall as desired
player_id = c.create_rectangle(
    c_middle[0] - (player_width / 2),  # __x0
    c_middle[1] - (player_height / 2),  # __y0
    c_middle[0] + (player_width / 2),  # __x1
    c_middle[1] + (player_height / 2),  #__y1
    fill='grey',
)

window.mainloop()
```

NOTE: I've made some minor edits to the variable names here to better adhere to Python style practices, e.g. `c_middle` instead of `cMiddle`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. If I were to center it along the x-axis but move it about 100 from the bottom of the canvas, how would I go about doing that. I might try doing the rather simple math and moving it down a certain amount, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do that. Again, I was thinking of moving it to about 100 from the bottom. Thanks again.

Comment: Since the values in `c_middle` are used to set the center of your rectangle, you can simply use a different y value. In this case, instead of dividing the height by 2 to get the *center* of the y axis, you can just subtract a number of pixels (e.g. 100) to offset your rectangle that far from the bottom: `c_middle = [int(c['width']) / 2, int(c['height']) - 100]`. Keeping the x value as-is `int(c['width']) / 2` just keeps your rectangle centered horizontally, but if you wanted to offset it left or right you'd just add or subtract an offset value in a similar fashion.